# Android wear app - blocking methods on UI thread

Tags: android, wear-os

I want to pass an Asset from my app to its wear app.

Sample code can be found here: https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/assets.html

However, I see 2 blocking methods being called, and it seems that they are done on the main thread:

```
 ConnectionResult result =
       mGoogleApiClient.blockingConnect(TIMEOUT_MS, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

And

```
 InputStream assetInputStream = Wearable.DataApi.getFdForAsset(
        mGoogleApiClient, asset).await().getInputStream();
```

Is it ok to call these methods on the UI thread? Or should I move this chunk of code to a background thread?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not okay to call those methods on the UI thread. In fact, calling `await()` on any [PendingResult](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/PendingResult.html) (such as what `getFdForAsset()` returns) on the UI thread will immediately throw an exception.

Instead, each method has an equivalent callback mechanism - for logging in, it is the standard [ConnectionCallbacks](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks.html) registered via [registerConnectionCallbacks](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient.html#registerConnectionCallbacks(com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks)) or for a `PendingResult` it is a [ResultCallback](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/ResultCallback.html) set by using the [setResultCallback()](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/PendingResult.html#setResultCallback(com.google.android.gms.common.api.ResultCallback%3CR%3E)) method.

Of course, you certainly could use any method for creating [separate threads](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html#Threads) - the simplest being an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html#AsyncTask) and then run all of those methods in a background thread instead of on the UI thread.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I actually do not get a crash when calling await(), and I made sure runs on the UI thread. Also, I find it very odd that google would post such a sample code and not mention that threading work is required.

Comment: Are you sure what you are saying is also true for code running on Wear devices?

Comment: In many cases, you'd retrieve assets in your [WearableListenerService](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/wearable/WearableListenerService.html) which runs all of its methods (including the `onDataChanged()` method in the example) on a background thread already.